# profiling WCF services with visual studio profiler

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

I am trying to profile a WCF service using visual studio profiler. So i created a profile by choosing asp.net application, and gave it the url of the web service. When i launch the session, it launches a web page to the site.

I then run my unit test using another visual studio client, but the test always fails with with communication exception, and the process that performance analyze is attached to exits out.

if i run the test again, it attached the process again, but the tests still fails with communication exception.

This is throwing my report off since its only accounting for the startup work that the application is supposed to do.

can someone point out what i am doing wrong ?